# How do I convert a decimal value into MM:SS on SQL?

Tags: sql, time, type-conversion, dataiku

I am using the Dataiku DSS platform for data recipes and in one of my datasets, there are four columns named `AvgACWTime_avg`, `AvgSpeedAns_avg`, `AvgACDTime_avg` and `AvgAbanTime_avg` for which there are numerical time values in seconds, simply stored as decimals. I would like to convert these into a HH:MM format, what code do I need for this? Assume that I would like any new columns to be called `ACWmin`, `Speedmin`, `ACDmin` and `Abanmin`.

I have tried using the following formulas:

```
WITH ACWmin AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (AvgACWTime_avg)) AS t(AvgACWTime_avg)
)
SELECT 
    CAST(AvgACWTime_avg AS decimal(12, 2)) / 60 
FROM 
    ACWmin;
FROM "database"."dataset"
```

and

```
DECLARE ACWmin datetime

SELECT ACWmin = DATEADD(mi, AvgACWTime_avg * 60, '00:00') 
FROM "database"."dataset"
```

Neither of them have worked for me. I don't understand whether I am missing something with syntax or there is something else that I'm not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For **mm:ss** do this:

```
to_string(trunc([DecimalValue])) + ":" +
to_string(trunc(60 * ([DecimalValue] - trunc([DecimalValue]))))
```

e.g:

```
SELECT
    to_string(trunc(AvgACWTime_avg)) + ":" +
    to_string(trunc(60 * (AvgACWTime_avg - trunc(AvgACWTime_avg)))) AS ACWmin
    
  , to_string(trunc(AvgSpeedAns_avg)) + ":" +
    to_string(trunc(60 * (AvgSpeedAns_avg - trunc(AvgSpeedAns_avg)))) AS Speedmin
    
  , to_string(trunc(AvgACDTime_avg)) + ":" +
    to_string(trunc(60 * (AvgACDTime_avg - trunc(AvgACDTime_avg)))) AS ACDmin
    
  , to_string(trunc(AvgAbanTime_avg)) + ":" +
    to_string(trunc(60 * (AvgAbanTime_avg - trunc(AvgAbanTime_avg)))) AS Abanmin
FROM
    YourTable;
```

For formatting decimal into **hh:mm:ss** use this:

```
to_string(trunc([DecimalValue])) + ":" +
to_string(trunc(60 * ([DecimalValue] - trunc([DecimalValue])))) + ":" +
to_string(trunc(60 * (60 * ([DecimalValue] - trunc([DecimalValue])) - trunc(60 * ([DecimalValue] - trunc([DecimalValue]))))))
```

You might want to use a function to make this useful elsewhere:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DecimalToMMSS (@decimalValue DECIMAL(10, 2))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @minutes INT = CAST(@decimalValue AS INT);
    DECLARE @seconds INT = CAST((@decimalValue - @minutes) * 60 AS INT);
    RETURN FORMAT(@minutes, '00') + ':' + FORMAT(@seconds, '00');
END;
```

or:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DecimalToHHMMSS (@decimalValue DECIMAL(10, 2))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hours INT = CAST(@decimalValue AS INT);
    DECLARE @minutes INT = CAST((@decimalValue - @hours) * 60 AS INT);
    DECLARE @seconds INT = CAST(((@decimalValue - @hours) * 60 - @minutes) * 60 AS INT);
    RETURN FORMAT(@hours, '00') + ':' + FORMAT(@minutes, '00') + ':' + FORMAT(@seconds, '00');
END;
```